# Speed improvements of MySQL MATCH query

Tags: mysql, performance, match

Trying to see if there is a way I can speed up a query I have built for a site I have been working on that utilized "MATCH"

```
$r=$this->query("SELECT product_id,`locale`,
       MATCH (description) AGAINST ('".$keyword."') as matches,
       description
   FROM search_index
   HAVING matches>0
      AND locale='".$locale."'
   ORDER BY matches DESC limit ".$limit);
```

Basically, I am querying a table with a small number of columns with about 6000 records. But it taking a few seconds each time - and hoping I can dial that down a bit.

Here is the table structure if it helps...

[image]

Not sure if I have the index set up properly, or perhaps changing table type? Or perhaps querying and getting results that fit the locale condition before I query for matches (or perhaps it is doing that part already...)

Thanks in advance for any insight.

---- update -----

Some more information based off the feedback from Rick

I tried modifying based on your feedback.
Here is an original sql

`SELECT product_id,locale, MATCH (description) AGAINST ('saw blade') as matches, description FROM search_index HAVING matches>0 AND locale='en_us' ORDER BY matches DESC`

I modified based off your feedback (though - probably incorrectly!)

`SELECT product_id,locale, MATCH (description) AGAINST ('saw blade') as matches, description FROM search_index WHERE MATCH (description) AGAINST ('saw blade') AND locale='en_us' ORDER BY matches DESC`

They both take about the same time to execute, unfortunately (about 6-7 seconds).

When I try an EXPLAIN on the latter query - I get this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change "HAVING" to "WHERE" and repeat the MATCH in the WHERE.

HAVING is not done until later; you need it to happen at WHERE time.

For further discussion, please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: Thanks. Updated question based on your feedback

Comment: Hmmm... Your rewritten query looks 'correct'.  Is the table `ENGINE=InnoDB`?  (I don't think that matters.)  How many rows in the table?  How many rows with 'saw blades'?  Try this:  `... AGAINST("sqw blades" IN BOOLEAN MODE) ...`

Comment: Yes, the table is InnoDB..

Tried adding "IN BOOLEAN MODE" and the query seemed to take about 2x the time to run (about 12s vs 6s).


There are about 6600 records in the table, and the query returns 450 of them currently.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up speeding this up significantly by switching the description field from varchar to text. Night and day difference. Not sure why... - but I will take it!